# Bitbucket Slack integration gives too much details

Tags: bitbucket, slack

We have Bitbucket integration with slack but it gives too much details in the chat. It pollutes the feed and makes it very difficult to follow. 
[image]

I don't want to have all these description. I want just a title instead.
Is there a way to customize message in slack?

Comment: I would also really like to customize Slack notifications from BitBucket, if anyone knows how to.